# How is numpy and pandas library able to change what print function does

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Both NumPy and pandas datatypes get printed very differently even though we are just passing the data to the print function rather than calling a method

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html

Comment: That looks like a global config used in the `__str__` methods of the various classes

Answer (score 3):

Every full-featured data type has conversion functions for conversion to string, `__str__`, and output, `__repr__`.  Both PANDAS and NumPy have implemented those methods as part of each data type's class definition -- those control how the data types appear.

You can look up details in any mid-level tutorial on classes.

Answer (score 2):

Prune's answer is correct, but I want to make it more concrete with an example.
The print function actually outputs whatever is returned by the instance's class's `__repr__` magic method
example:
let's say you have a Person class:

```
class Person:
    pass

p = Person()

print(p)
```

The result will be something like:

```
<__main__.Person object at 0x000000D9D5034508>
```

Now let's implement the `__repr__` magic method:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"< Person Name: {self.name} >"

p = Person("Robert")

print(p)
```

I also added the constructor to demonstrate how one may use it.
The result will be:

```
< Person Name: Robert >
```

And that's how Numpy and Pandas are able to display the array and Dataframes like that.